# scope.$observe is not a function in an AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Take the following directive:

```
appDirectives.directive('drFadeHighlight', ['$animate', '$timeout', function ($animate, $timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            isWatchObject: '='
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            element.addClass('dr-fade-highlight');          
            scope.$observe('isEnabled', function () {
                console.log('i observed...');
                console.log(arguments);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

I have stripped it right back, to show only the part I am having an issue with.

When this directive is applied to an element i receive the error:

`TypeError: scope.$observe is not a function`

Am i missing something very silly here? I have a watcher (`$watch`) watching a more comprehensive object `isWatchObject` and this is fine.

I could simply add `isEnabled` to the scope and 2-way bind on it, though `$observe` would be much nicer here.

I use `$watch` a lot, though not so much `$observe` - so figure i must be missing something..

Any ideas why this is throwing an error?

Comment: You should pass as parameter $scope not scope

Comment: @fals - that doesn't matter at all - i could call it `bob` and it would still reference the `scope`. And in controllers, we do use `$scope` - directives we use `scope` - don't ask me why, it's what i learned when going through a bunch of tutorials a couple years back

Comment: If you use scope the injection will not merge all methods from $scope service. The injection works by name

Comment: @Fals - you're wrong - this doesn't apply to the link method of the directive

Comment: @fals - not in the directive it doesn't. And in controllers we use the minification-safe way; `.controller('transactionContactCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){}]);` - which, by the way, would work if you did `.controller('transactionContactCtrl', ['$scope', function(bob){}]);`  too - `$scope` would be known as `bob` in the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$observe` would be placed on an attribute. Check out the [$compile.directive.Attributes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes) docs for more information. In your example, you would do something like (asuming `isEnabled` is an attribute like `is-enabled="true"`) ...

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {       
    attr.$observe('isEnabled', function (value) {
        console.log('i observed...');
        console.log(value);
    });
}
```

Comment: Son of a ...... i just realized this as you answered lol. smh. Thanks :) - will accept as soon as i can :)